Why I can't see the console write when using async await Task?
I'm new in C#.
I wrote a code run C# as below and run in main console:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class HelloWorld 
{
  static void Main() 
  {
    Task t = example1();
  }
  
  static async Task DoWork()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( " Hello World! " ); 
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) 
    { 
       Console.WriteLine( " Working..{0} " ,i); 
       await   Task.Delay( 1000 ); 
    } 
  }
  
  static async Task example1()
  {
      await DoWork();
      Console.WriteLine( " First async Run End " ); 
  }
}

I pressed run and get the answer:

Could anyone help me understand what's wrong happend in first code?
And how to realize the async/await correctly?
I have read a lot about async/await C#, but still confuse it.
Thanks.
But when I try to add the t.Wait() in Main() like:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class HelloWorld 
{
  static void Main() 
  {
    Task t = example1();
    t.Wait();
  }
  
  static async Task DoWork()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( " Hello World! " ); 
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) 
    { 
       Console.WriteLine( " Working..{0} " ,i); 
       await   Task.Delay( 1000 ); 
    } 
  }
  
  static async Task example1()
  {
      await DoWork();
      Console.WriteLine( " First async Run End " ); 
  }
}

I can get the answer:

I think I'm not realize the async/await correctly.

instead of void Main(), use async Task Main(), and await t instead of t.Wait()

You should be using
static async Task Main() 
{
    await example1();
}


In your first example your process will exit directly after reaching the first await. And this will prevent anything after any await to run. Making the main method async Task Main() will ensure your process stays alive until the returned task completes.
I would recommend How async await really works  if you want to know more about the internal details of async.

Thanks for your replyment. I try the code, it seems not work because my Main() is entry point. And thanks for your link. I will read it!!
Otherwise, your inference is right, because I do an experiment that  trying add Console.ReadLine(); after Task t = example1(); in first example. Thank you!

@harryLin async main has existed since c# 7.1. If you are running anything older you likely want to update, especially if you are learning.

Thank you recommend me. It is useful very much

Well, as with any variable, you're just not using the object being created by your function. Consider this code for instance:
class MyClass
{
    int CreateInt() => 5;
    void DoSomething()
    {
        var a = CreateInt();
    }
}

You don't use the variable a in your code, so you get the exact same warning here. The dame aplies to your variable of type Task.
So how does one use a variable of that type. Usually it's by awaiting. You could call Wait on the object. However that's usually a very bad idea, the same as using .Result on it, because they block your thread and thus hinder it from doing anything while waiting. What you should do instead is await myTask.

Thanks for your relpyment. Could I treat Thread.Sleep() and task.Wait() as similar concepts? If so, would it also not be advisable to use Thread.Sleep()

@harryLin blocking a thread is not inherently bad, sometimes you want that of course. In these cases you may use Thread.Sleep - which is why the function even exists. The same applies to Wait. However in most cases, you want an await instead, as you don't wont to block the thread.
